# Writing an universal fill method for several classes in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, inheritance

For example, I have two classes:

```
class A {
  protected $x, $y;
}

class B {
  protected $x, $z;
}
```

In each of them I need a method to fill the data from array. So since it is possible to write an universal filler, I'd like to write this code once.

In 5.4 I believe traits could make it possible to write someting like

```
protected function fill(array $row) {
  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $this->$$key = $value;
  }
}
```

and just use it.

But how do I do this in 5.3?

Comment: Common base class is not an option?

Comment: so create a parameterized constructor in both the classes ...

Comment: Try changing `$this->$$key` to `$this->{$key}`.

Comment: @Sverri Those are the same things.

Comment: @complex857 maybe this is just me, but when I use a base class, it is searching for vars in that base class, not in a child

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Thanks, thak worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an abstract class and have classes that share functionality extend it

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected function fill(array $row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
}

class A extends Base {
    protected $x, $y;
}

class B extends Base {
    protected $x, $z;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but since I use $this-> here, it is looking for variable in parent, I assume. So with test like this: `<?php

abstract class Base
{
    function fill(array $row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            $this->$$key = $value;
        }
    }
}

class A extends Base {
    protected $x, $y;
}

$a = new A();
$a->fill(array('x' => '1', 'y' => '2'));
var_dump($a);
` I got PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: x in /var/www/html/model/test.php on line 7
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in /var/www/html/model/test.php on line 7

Comment: Use the `$this->{$key} = $value` form, the variable-variable thing wont work here (probably php parser quirk, i'm not sure).